# "Try it" facility suffers a double-encoding bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

> [image: Try It: Personal Finance &amp; Money [edit]]

As you can clearly see from the above, the ampersand in the site name in the "Try It" section of [the API method documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) has been double-encoded. This affects any site with an ampersand in the name, and looks ugly.

[Here's a link to a live, second example (*English Language & Usage*).](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#site=english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.